# Persist SelectedIndex of DropDownList in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to automatically select the last index which was selected before called the action. Inside the action I put the selected index into the ViewData["SelectedIndex"]. But now how do I set the DropDownList with the value set in the ViewData.

Answer (score 0):

john,

try something like this (based on your own strongly typed view model):

```
<%=Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.EquipmentID, new SelectList(Model.Equipment, "id", "Name", ViewData["SelectedIndex"]), "-- Select Equipment --") %>
```

might (should!!) just work.

**[edit]** - you may have to pass in the 'name' property to ViewData (i.e. ViewData["SelectedIndex"] = item.Name; ), rather than the id in the above. just thought more about it there!!

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by passing the name property!

Comment: john, i was suggesting that you try either yuor models 'id' property OR the text based 'name' /description property.